# Erlang program faster with tracing

Tags: performance, erlang

I am carrying out some evaluation measurements on a program to test the execution time and how a tracer that checks the execution of the original system effects the performance of the original system.  The tracing program does **not** interfere with the system and no communication between them takes place except from receiving the trace messages.

The results I have so far are an average of `953.14` microseconds for the program without the tracing switched on compared to `937` microseconds with the tracing switched on.  The timing is calculated using `statistics(wall_clock)` function.

My idea was that since I have an extra process(es) from the tracer and the tracing mechanism would require their own processing power, it would slow the system down rather than speeding it up.  Is there any known reason why this could happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you run the measure once or several time? As you use the wall_clock, you are including in this measure potential perturbation of the environment, wait for messages... , and you are not evaluation the CPU time. the example below shows it:

```
1> F = fun() -> receive _ -> ok after 5000 -> timout end end.
#Fun<erl_eval.20.111823515>
2> F().
timout
3> statistics(wall_clock),F(),statistics(wall_clock).       
{965829,5016}
4>
```

The function F obviously does not need 5 seconds of CPU time, but is only waiting for 5 second.

This means that you should make the measure several time, generally do not use the first execution time that may include the necessary time to load the module code, and take care of the environment - what are the other process running on the same machine, and be sure that the time measured is not the result of waiting states.

If you use runtime instead of wall_clock you should see the CPU time needed and therefore an increased time when tracing your code. Beware that this increase of time may be hidden by the usage of multi core.

Comment: I ran the measure for 9 times for each setup and the question is related to the average time of these 9 times.  Are you suggesting that I use `runtime` instead of `wall_clock`? I am running the measure on a multi-core system.

Comment: Using runtime you will get the sum of each core activity to run your code. With this option you should get an idea of the trace option cost. As I said in the answer, the extra cost that you will get will be, at least partially, hidden by the concurrent execution on your multi core system.